# C# - Insert Session value along with dynamic Gridview's data

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I found this code (Credits to: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/dynamically-adding-and-deleting-rows-in-gridview-and-saving/ ) in which a Gridview is created dynamically.

I would like to add in the "P_deaseases" datatable, the Session["pa_id"] along with the gridview data (using a parameter). The code works very well inserting the gridview data only, without the extra column I added "P_Id". I have made some comments in the places I've changed the code.

Despite the changes, there is still an error.

Could you please suggest what should I change?

Code:

```
 private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }


    private void InsertRecords(StringCollection sc)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        string[] splitItems = null;
        const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO P_deasease (P_Id,Nosos,Situ,Year_d,Therapy) VALUES (@p_id)"; //I added the P_Id and the parameter
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pa_id"]); //I added that
        foreach (string item in sc)
        {
            if (item.Contains(","))
            {
                splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3]);
            }
        }

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            connection.Open();


            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sb.ToString(), connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id", id); //I added that
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }


        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        lblMessage.Text = "Οι εγγραφές αποθηκεύτηκαν!";
    }


  protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        StringCollection sc = new StringCollection();
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the values  
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    //add them to the collections with a comma "," as the delimited values  
                    sc.Add(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}", box1.Text, box2.Text, ddl1.SelectedItem.Text, box3.Text));
                    rowIndex++;
                }
                //Call the method for executing inserts  
                InsertRecords(sc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added parameter the wrong way. Note that the foreach adds strings like this:

```
<already built sql expression> (s1,s2,s3,s4)
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO P_deasease (Nosos,Situ,Year_d,Therapy) VALUES (s1,s2,s3,s4)
```

Which is a valid insert clause. Now with your addition this looks like:

```
INSERT INTO P_deasease (P_Id,Nosos,Situ,Year_d,Therapy) VALUES (@p_id)(s1,s2,s3,s4)
```

Which is not valid at all.

Now you probably wanted to have P_Id populated with the same value for all new entries. That should be done with something like:

```
    const string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO P_deasease (P_Id,Nosos,Situ,Year_d,Therapy) VALUES "; //I added the P_Id and the parameter
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pa_id"]); //I added that
    foreach (string item in sc)
    {
        if (item.Contains(","))
        {
            splitItems = item.Split(",".ToCharArray());
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}(@p_id, '{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}'); ", sqlStatement, splitItems[0], splitItems[1], splitItems[2], splitItems[3]);
        }
    }
```

But that is a strange thing to do, to be honest. If P_Id is a primary key column, that would fail because you cannot have two rows with the same primary key. Did you actually consider setting auto-generating ID for the column in your database?

Comment: The table already has a primary key Id which is autoincrement, but i want to insert another id which belongs to other table (thats why it is a session).  Your answer seems having a very right aproach (and thank you very much), but shouldn't assign the integer id in the parameter?

Comment: @natso, oh i see. than check out my suggested option. I did not tested it obviously, but it should give you an idea of what went wrong how to fix that